# Why won't any image show when I try to use css to do so?

Tags: css, image, background

I am very new to html and css. I am trying to set my background image and nothing is working. I have created a folder in where my html files are, and I have also tried using a direct path as shown on the image's properties. Nothing I have tried has worked. I have read a lot of instructions, watched videos online, etc, etc, etc. I hope someone can help me! It seems so simple and yet I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work. Below is how I have everything.

```
<html> 
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-image:url ("C:/Users/owner/Desktop/site files/images/grass.jpg");}




</style>




</head>



<body>





</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no protocol in your url, try prefixing it with file://
and that is only if you are opening the html document on your local computer.

Answer (score 1):

It likely has to do with your local URL. Put the image with your code and use a relative path.

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    background-image: url("../images/grass.jpg");
  }
</style>
```

**Note**: I'd also encourage you to avoid spaces or other non-conventional filename characters.

Answer (score 0):

As silly as it sounds, it worked for me when there's no space between url and (

I also changed the file link to something like `"file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/face.jpg"` (opening the desired image in your browser should result in this format in the address bar)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you next:

1) Add something inside body, to make page not empty

```
<body>Some text</body>
```

2) There is folder with blank sign (space) in the name in your path - it can be problem!

I'd advice you to place your background image in the same folder with your HTML file and write path such way:

```
body { background-image: url('./grass.jpg'); }
```

Notice special signs which can be used in path:

./ current dirrectory

../ one dirrectory up